# XSL 1.0 Count Distinct with "following:[element]" and exclude certain elements

Tags: xslt, count, distinct, grouping

So I've been struggling with counting distinct elements. I have this data. Code is ready for copy paste.

```
<CustInvoiceTable class="entity">
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <ItemId>ITM-0000088</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <ItemId>ITM-0000088</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <ItemId>ITM-0000091</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <ItemId>ITM-0000091</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <ItemId>ITM-0000098</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <ItemId>ITM-0000098</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <ItemId>ITM-0000086</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <ItemId>ITM-0000086</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <ItemId>ITM-0000062</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>2</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <ItemId>ITM-0000062</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>2</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <ItemId>ITM-0000111</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <ItemId>ITM-0000111</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <ItemId>ITM-0000089</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <ItemId>ITM-0000089</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <ItemId>ITM-0000092</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <ItemId>ITM-0000092</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <ItemId>ITM-0000101</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <ItemId>ITM-0000101</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <ItemId>ITM-0000102</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <ItemId>ITM-0000102</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <ItemId>ITM-0000083</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <ItemId>ITM-0000083</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <ItemId>ITM-0000067</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <ItemId>ITM-0000067</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>

    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <ItemId>ITM-0000125</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>0</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>

    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <ItemId>ITM-0000069</ItemId>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>

    <!-- Excluding these 3 elements will result in the correct count -->
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <ItemId>ITM-0000083</ItemId>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <ItemId>ITM-0000092</ItemId>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <ItemId>ITM-0000098</ItemId>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>

</CustInvoiceTable>
```

I want to count distinct ItemId values where CgiBundleLines = 1. The result must be 11. My XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:key name="Lines-by-ItemId" match="CustInvoiceTable/McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine" use="CustInvoiceTable/McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine/ItemId" />

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <CountOne><xsl:value-of select="count(CustInvoiceTable/McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine[not(ItemId = following::ItemId) and McsCmBilProductItem/CgiBundleLines = 1])"/></CountOne>
        <CountOne><xsl:value-of select="count(CustInvoiceTable/McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine[not(ItemId = following::ItemId) and McsCmBilProductItem/CgiBundleLines = 1 and boolean(McsCmBilProductItem) = 1])"/></CountOne>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I run this i get a count of 8. It looks like the last 3 McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine elements causes the ItemId's not to be counted. Commeting these 3 returns the count = 11, which is what i want. So how do I exclude the last 3 elements or make my XSL code not count them.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a separate predicate `/CustInvoiceTable/McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine[McsCmBilProductItem/CgiBundleLines = 1][not(ItemId = preceding-sibling::McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine/ItemId)]` then you can count only those elements with the `McsCmBilProductItem/CgiBundleLines = 1` condition.

So

```
count(/CustInvoiceTable/McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine[McsCmBilProductItem/CgiBundleLines = 1][not(ItemId = preceding-sibling::McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine/ItemId)])
```

gives 11.